# How to search index Drupal content to Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, search, drupal

We are planning to implement search feature using the Mongodb as search index server. Is there module that helps to add the Mongodb connector as Search Server and then add search index mapping to push Drupal content to Mongodb Server.

Any equivalent module in Drupal 9 for [MongoDB Indexer](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb_indexer)

Also please suggest any contribute module to use the search query from Mongodb Index to display result in Drupal CMS.